# Характерные ошибки

Tags: орфоэпия

Получил задание ,- "*Определить суть характерной ошибки,  сопровождающих произнесение слов*

**Юрисконсульт, конкурентоспособный, компетентый, компрометировать, эскорт**".

С двумя крайними вроде понятно, юрисТкосульт и эКскорт, а как в остальных ошибиться можно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть ошибки - произнесение и написание согласных во всех данных словах:ЮрисТконсульт, конкурентНоспособный, компеНтентный, компромеНтировать, эКскорт. Ещё пишут "дермаНтин".

Причины разные, иногда- существование ассоциаций с однокоренными словами юрис-юрисТ(но юрисдикция, юриспруденция),конкурентНый,однако чаще - ассоциации с паронимами и просто привычка произнесения похожих сочетаний согласных - КОМПЕНсация,КОММЕНтировать, ЭКСпансия и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо. А то сижу гадаю, как правильно слова исковеркать. :-)

Comment: Инсценировал трансцендентный инциНдент. Легко запутаться языку!